# Selecting Multi-line strings through Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, cryptography, multiline

I am using Entity Framework 4 in C# (Yes I know I should upgrade but thats besides the point).

I have 70,000 private RSA Keys stored in a database 
The format is like this:
Note - this is a demo key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Note: for some reason the END RSA line doesnt format properly on Stack Overflow.

However, when I try to select the key back through entity framework, I get only the following:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I believed that this might be SQL Server (2008 in my case) terminating the string at the new line character ('\n')
So I wrote a stored proc to try and replace it server side, before being returned to the calling application.

Ended up with something like this

```
Declare @str as nvarchar(max)
Declare @strReplaced as nvarchar(max)
set @str = (select PrivateKey from PrivateKeys where Id = @ID)
set @strReplaced = (select (REPLACE(@str, CHAR(10), '<<newline>>')))
select @strReplaced
```

When run on the sql server (the stored proc) - it gives me the private key with the appropriate <> replacements
However when I execute the stored proc via the following C# code, it is still terminating the result on the first line of the key.

```
var str = o.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Execute dbo.GetPrivateKey " + Id.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(str.ToList()[0]);
```

Can someone suggest a solution to allow my C# code to get access to the whole RSA Key?

When executing my stored proc in the SQL Server Management Studio: I get
`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----<<newline>>MIICXwIBAAKBgQDuCFrUx55g9yqezNvzSpX0YegUDnrp0IP7jsMab0NVqAgl/azO<<newline>>qbp5SNe10mAYJNDsxBS0AHYSOrAHApgKPgWTKOE5gFUKxaB1eJgIDEMODEMODEMODEMO<<newline>>0PU0Kma2/8Znv23JFUDrO3Sk8Ft++aT8crCs45ygnJVNSdgsU0MDEMODEMODEMODEMO<<newline>>awKBgAXv6PqRNvFuEg5Pt+0IjwTMEHLqPBPEh5k2eS1aRYKyl/T40fe5SaXiMxWb<<newline>>f8SUoLXDPdOdkXqBqZfOs94hjtk6mRDZuBN9MWL7F4D+b6/n4s+YDEMODEMODEMODEMO<<newline>>kEr7DrtF/n/kDrH/Pty6pyHCfGLVLMtG6cFYIPncyYzViLTDAkEA+riR/e+elYVe<<newline>>bc+KPq9NlSXAFz21R00puCUJhrVBNcVZnKw2hV8D9Ie4b+WMaPcGh/7gHAiUC84o<<newline>>JpLA8EjGPQJBAPMLZGRwcvNiUW7gl2EBIq33gDZvefzQC4kr5J2SFLaA4lX/wKMJ<<newline>>ymHJdjQlmo5nKd7qdmg0DwbUSOjCcux/RpkCQQDXde/XX9kIxD9NQ2wV0DhQ4LFU<<newline>>J/OXlxZ2yD+Tnr7lFFN/QghU8Vuc0G4eRPR2kg5X6FBya3nQ5miDgl8j76pDAkEA<<newline>>pud2zrTMxBul8BDP4+gqll18jcRt0sV7fERvaMT+0gL/M2QamRevgd22ipKbBAUV<<newline>>P4f1Jtj6aFqVQ9n8RewtuwJBAL4iLMt/GWg71PBQhPlZlkDlmDGoDF1Ou6MYlONv<<newline>>z24JA/EMdx3Jx1/WG7xyzqmEJcVGk/8O/NWtP5DXQEFBLnw=<<newline>>-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----<<newline>>`

When executing the stored proc via C# code:
`string sConnectionString = "InsertConnectionStringHere";
                                using (var conn = new           System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
                            using (var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("GetPrivateKey", conn)
                            {
                                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

```
                        })
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DomainID", vTransaction.Domain.Id));
                            var vReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            vReader.Read();
                            var vResult = vReader.GetValue(0);
                            Console.WriteLine(vResult);
                            conn.Close();
                        }`
```

It gives me -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Its like whatever the cause is, is affecting SQL at a low level. So it impacts both direct raw SQL and the Entity Framework that rests on top of it.

Edit -- On closer inspection, I am using SQL Server Express- does it have limitations that might affect the strings returned?

EDIT----
I modified the Stored Proc to convert the text field to Binary data and then send it to the caller.
via this code
`select CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), @str )`

It works on the SQL Server, but when called remotely via the C# code, it only gets 62 bytes of data, when converted to string - once again, those bytes construct the '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

I am at a loss....

Comment: It should work nonetheless. Question is: Are you using EF *properly* - or have you set up EF but getting the data via SQL?

Comment: Sorry, missed the Stored Procedure part. Why are you getting it via SP at all?

Comment: Using the Stored Procedure was an attempt at solving the issue.
If I attempt to use 
entityName.PrivateKey -  this also gives me the single line, opposed to the full string.

Comment: That's weird! Am using EF with multiline entries too, no such behaviour!
What's the datatype of your PrivateKey field / property? varchar(max)?

Comment: In the database it is datatype nvarchar(max)


`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Domains](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [DomainName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [PrivateKey] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [Added] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [PriceUSD] [float] NOT NULL,
 [Length] [int] NOT NULL,
 [TargetWord] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,`

Comment: This is all damn peculiar. Copy one such PrivateKey from SQLServer (Express doesn't matter) over to a text editor that will let you view the underlying hex codes. Check whether there is any other character than 0A 0D. Maybe there is a record separator character in it (1E if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: As a workaround, you could precede this line in your SP: `set @strReplaced = (select (REPLACE(@str, CHAR(10), '<<newline>>')))`  with `set @strReplaced = (select (REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), CHAR(10))))` to make sure you also catch the \r. Not exactly a solution but narrowed down to \r being the culprit.

Comment: That didnt help unfortunately.
When I am loading the keys into the database, I had to do something weird in order to maintain the formatting.
I split first on the \n to get each line, then I reconstruct line by line, adding a \n to the string.
That being the case - I don't think there is a Char(13) present. (when I try to replace that  - it doesnt detect any present)
The really strange thing is that even when converting the field to varbinary it still just gives me the bytes for the first line.

Comment: Viewing in the hex editor shows that the database contains hex code 20 in place of the new line character.

Comment: A real blind shot there but... check your connection string. Are you pointing to the live DB or accidentally still to a test DB, I.e. not getting the *real deal*? This is so weird.

Comment: Im gonna mark it as closed - I ended up working around it : Instead storing the PrivateKey as a byte[] so when it gets pulled back it disregards any potential termination characters.
Thanks anyway for trying
(Note: was just working with one database - so its still a mystery)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string key =
                "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                "MIICXQIDEMODEMODEMODEMODEMOEbGslt0N21onxRjBUwXFKI7CN6clxPAS+nEUK\n" +
                "BZAEiJUDJLqcGa37EZv40UQnmGKpLZO3ypee9qvKRVC4Q3Oi3S+Ukfet7eJYvCwr\n" +
                "WlneDOqvzyDz8cwlLcE2YhOnCMLYJ3v3YSt0n10oryaKyADDbCd5PmBbUwIEB7CO\n" +
                "+QKBgCtLDEMODEMODEMODEMODEMOnNVbWYfVLhFJpdS1+5dTZbkOg6zaP+A/VKf1w\n" +
                "3psFl7VfbggqiEvAi+4hTULVZu0W0wqPQUkw+rGzVT8Fg1uwBrzUKScJbscuRE/J\n" +
                "1I6iizZ0sudjUynn+EORc12p1NRslf2BUW3nFIognt849r9JAkEA1V+5aGmJLZPP\n" +
                "xZ/ETst7tb1WMeOvNxu+s/h2kcW6+WCvlUErYiB2/E/LkTbYGXu5/OHIMDgbQbB+\n" +
                "28Bu7lYmUwJBAM12343234235AEIDmvGJChsPOaqwnClV/fSEx/6E8DXMhDHTENA\n" +
                "STt+v4k1rlkSlM2aliZ8kz2u8K45SepsVwECQQCmECecqVtfuIvC+8EKvlM536OT\n" +
                "XrLIeDOkRak8yRqQFEZzAlOXkOtKIxHBJuVT39sPK+xzU30FwRdLE858eBphAkB+\n" +
                "LExh7ejTrxN3dHr1mDhJWoLzm59dzgwfmuEznnH+OmMZSAY21IouIAXjnKfXeCLo\n" +
                "fRvUv5EuQkvGUJi1/25JAkAXZy7yjsJxaNBGB9TxakoHHnI2yWI/R9yewhzLorNo\n" +
                "Oj49W6l9uaWaNxxmCrNZRIZoDEMODEMODEMODEMODEMO\n" +
                "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

            Regex expr = new Regex("-.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            key = expr.Replace(key, "").Trim();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This wont help - the issue is that the full string (the key) is stored on the SQL server, for some reason - the string is not returned to the C# code so I cannot execute a regex on something that the C# code has no access to.

Comment: In the data base what is the length of the Var.  It may not be long enough to contain all the characters.  It usually defaults to 256 and the key by itself is 256.  With the two extra lines it is exceeding the default size in the database.

Comment: The nvarchar is at max length  (  nvarchar(max))
The field contains all the data - When using sql studio, I can select the data fine. Its just when I try to do the same from C# - it gets truncated to the end of the first line of the RSA Key.

Comment: You have 888 characters.  Make sure also in your command you specify the length like tis :             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024);

Comment: That size argument relates to the parameter being used in the stored proc / query. It has nothing to do with return values from the database.
To clarify - I am not having any difficulties putting data into the database, I am having issues getting data out of the database. So making changes to parameters will not solve this problem.